# Business Account(BAccount) Fielddefaulting not working

Tags: acumatica

I'm having an issue with this particular field defaulting method working. I've done many in the past with no issues. For some reason it's not assigning the ClassID on the Business Accounts page. I've gone through the debugger and stepped through cus.CustomerClassID which contained the correct value; additionally e.NewValue was assigned correctly in the debugger. But when the page actually opens the field remains blank. Is there a special case with field defaulting for BAccountMaint due to the generic inquiry?

```
 protected void BAccount_ClassID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e, PXFieldDefaulting InvokeBaseHandler)
    {
        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);

        BAccount row = (BAccount)e.Row;

        AR.Customer cus = PXSelect<AR.Customer, Where<AR.Customer.acctCD, Equal<Required<AR.Customer.acctCD>>>>.Select(Base, row.AcctCD);
        if (row.AcctCD != null)
        {

            e.NewValue = cus.CustomerClassID;
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have set up the class ID appropriately in both Customer and BAccount as well.

Comment: Did you check whtr there is any other possible events/attributes re-writing your value?

Comment: Well, out of the box Acumatica doesn't write default values to the ClassID in BAccount(well from my understanding). I only found the normal field defaulting method in the source code, but I already took the normal procedure to override the method. Really confused why it's not writing the values to the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieved a correct result by using rowselecting event instead of field defaulting.